# In Xcode 12, many XIBs are stuck with "View as: iPhone 11"—how can I fix this?

Tags: xcode, ipad, interface-builder, xib, xcode12

In Xcode 12, many XIBs are stuck with "View as: iPhone 11"—how can I fix this? I need to view as iPad.

Here is an example:[image: Interface Builder in Xcode 12]

Similar questions about this (from past Xcode versions) have said to change "Size" property in "Simulated Metrics" in the Attributes inspector. However, here is what the options are in that list:

[image: Simulated Metrics]

Bizarrely, most of my XIBs render as iPad but I can't change which iPad model is used. My app target only has iPad and Landscape orientations enabled:

[image]

So I'm very confused why it would show anything other than landscape iPad options in Interface builder. Also, my scheme is set to build on iPad.

Please let me know a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Look at your first screen shot in the question. Look at the lower left. See where it says "View as iPhone 11"?

[image]

That's a menu. Click it and choose a different device from the menu.